# Comparing a character in a Rust string using indexing

Tags: string, iterator, rust

I want to read strings from "input.txt" and leave only those which have no `#` (comment) symbol at the start of the line. I wrote this code:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open("input.txt").unwrap());
    let lines: Vec<String> = file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
    let mut iter = lines.iter().filter(|&x| x.chars().next() != "#".chars().next());
    println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
}
```

But this line

```
|&x| x.chars().next() != "#".chars().next()
```

smells bad to me, because it can look like this `|x| x[0] == "#"` and I can't check the second character in the string.

So how I can refactor this code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rust strings are stored as a sequence of bytes representing characters in UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding, so byte indexing can leave you inside a character, which is obviously unsafe. But getting a code point by index is an O(n) operation. Moreover, indexing code points is not what you really want to do, because there are code points which do not even have associated characters, like diacritics or other modifiers. Indexing grapheme clusters is closer to the correct approach, but is is usually needed in text rendering or, probably, language processing.

What I mean is that indexing a string is hard to define properly, and what most people usually want is wrong. Hence Rust does not provide a generic index operation on strings.

Occasionally, however, you do need to index strings. For example, if you know in advance that your string contains only ASCII characters or if you are working with binary data. In this case Rust, of course, provides all necessary means.

First, you can always obtain a view of the underlying sequence of bytes. `&str` has `as_bytes()` method which returns `&[u8]`, a slice of bytes the string consists of. Then you can use usual indexing operation:

```
x.as_bytes()[0] != b'#'
```

Note the special notation: `b'#'` means "ASCII character `#` of type `u8`", i.e. it is a byte character literal (also note that you don't need to write `"#".chars().next()` to get character `#`, you can just write `'#'` - a plain character literal). This is unsafe, however, because `&str` is UTF-8-encoded string and the first character can consist of more than one byte.

The proper way to handle ASCII data in Rust is to use the [ascii crate](https://crates.io/crates/ascii). You can go from `&str` to `&AsciiStr` with the `as_ascii_str()` method. Then you can use it like this:

```
extern crate ascii;
use ascii::{AsAsciiStr, AsciiChar};

// ...

x.as_ascii_str().unwrap()[0] != AsciiChar::Hash
```

This way you will need slightly more typing but you will get much more safety in return, because `as_ascii_str()` checks that you work with ASCII data only.

Sometimes, however, you just want to work with binary data, without really interpreting it as characters, even if the source contains some ASCII characters. This can happen, for example, when you're writing a parser for some markup language like Markdown. In this case you can treat the whole input as a sequence of bytes:

```
use std::io::{Read, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open("/etc/hosts").unwrap());
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
    let mut iter = buf.split(|&c| c == b'\n').filter(|line| line[0] != b'#');
    println!("{:?}", iter.next().unwrap());
}
```

Comment: `x[].as_bytes()[0] != b'#'` is not *unsafe* in any meaningful sense. It doesn't threaten memory safety, it doesn't involve invalid `char` values, it doesn't do funky things with types, and it isn't even particularly likely to do something meaningless. In UTF-8, multi-byte code points are exclusively composed of bytes > 127 (i.e. not ASCII), so searching for a byte with value 35 is a perfectly fine way to find occurrences of the U+0023 code point. But granted: It is bad style, and dropping to bytes is a bad habit for other text processing task.

Comment: @delnan, OK, in this particular case you're right. Unsafe (given the sense which is usually used in the context of Rust) probably the wrong word for this. However, writing the same thing for any index other than 0 is meaningless and incorrect, and the question author explicitly asked for checking also the second character and probably others.

Comment: Using the index 1 to try and check the second code point or grapheme cluster would be incorrect. But byte indexing is not necessarily incorrect. The properties of UTF-8 allow things like sub string searches to be written in terms of bytes. It's often pointless, yes (`char` iterators are usually better, and many algorithms are already provided by libstd), but let's not shoot the message.